# Tailwindcss in Figma

Tags: tailwind-css, figma-api

I wonder if it is possible to use Tailwindcss with Figma? And if someone does, is there any example to see? I saw that it is possible to export colors from Figma and import them in taiwind config. But what about Tailwindcss utilities? Also that it should work for Tailwind v1. Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is not really an option for Figma to import such things until the new plugins feature goes out of closed beta. However I've been working on bringing tailwind styles and components [here](https://github.com/impulse/tailwindcss-figma-kit), hope this helps.

cheers!

Comment: A plugin has been released that appears to address this functionality you should check it out. It's called "Tailwind CSS"

Comment: @MarioRicalde the plugin is by me. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Figma decided to shut down the tailwindcss integration, apparently to focus on more and better design functionality. I just read that recently (November 2021).

Comment: source? why would they do that